# Rotate Anchor Text?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to rotate an arrow so it faces down, but not sure if this is possible

HTML

```
<a href="/test/">test <span id="rotate">&raquo;</span></a>
```

CSS

```
span#rotate{ 
-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
-o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to keep the element behaving like the inline span that it is, but also want to rotate it, then you will need to use `display: inline-block;` on it. This won't force it to a new line like `display: block;` naturally would.

Here is the correct code (jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/joshnh/wZpP9/):

```
span#rotate{
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline; /* Used to get IE 6 & 7 to behave */
    zoom: 1; /* Used to get IE 6 & 7 to behave */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); 
       -moz-transform: rotate(90deg); 
        -ms-transform: rotate(90deg); 
         -o-transform: rotate(90deg);  
            transform: rotate(90deg);
               filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=0); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the element to be a `block` element for `rotate` to work.

try adding:

```
display:block;
width:10px;
height:10px;
```